# React fill SideNavBar from top to bottom with other components on the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, navigation

[image]

> I want my sidenavbar to continue over the whole page but when i add the other
> sections(home, contact & projects) which are just regular functional components
> with a div and h1, they create their own space on the page. is there a better
> solution to creating different sections on a page? i have tried rendering the components
> from index and app.js but without success, i am currently rendering SidenavBar
> from index.js and my sections are getting rendered from app.js.

```
     import React from "react";
     import "../Section.css";

     function HomeSection() {
     return (
      <div className="Section" id="Home">
     HomeSection
     <h1>Home</h1>
     </div>
     );
    }

   export default HomeSection;
```

> here is an example of the sections, the section.css only centers the text on the page.

```
  function SideNavBar() {
  const [titleActive, setTitleActive] = useState(HomeSection);
  return (
   <div className="SideNavBar">
   <Stickybox>
     <ul className="SideBarList">
       {SideBarInfo.map((info, key) => {
         return (
          <li
            key={key}
             className="rad"
              onClick={() => {
              console.log(info.title + " clicked");
              setTitleActive(info.title);
               }}
              id={titleActive === info.title ? "active" : ""}
              >
               <Link
               onClick={() => {
                console.log(info.title + " clicked");
                setTitleActive(info.title);
              }}
              id={titleActive === info.title ? "active" : ""}
              activeClass="active"
              to={info.title}
              spy={true}
              smooth={true}
              offset={50}
              duration={500}
              >
              <div id="title">{info.title}</div>
             /Link>
             <Link
                activeClass="active"
                to={info.title}
                spy={true}
                smooth={true}
                offset={50}
                duration={500}
              >
               <div id="bild">{info.bild}</div>
             </Link>
           </li>
         );
       })}
     </ul>
   </Stickybox>
   </div>
   );
  }

    export default SideNavBar;

     // this is the css for sidebar
    .SideNavBar {
     width: 250px;
     min-height: 5000px;
     background-color: rgb(47, 167, 223);
     height: 100vh;
     }
```

> this is my sidenavbar component.

[image]

> My sidenavbar works as intended if i remove the sections, i have tried setting a max width and transparent background for the sections so they dont overwrite the sidenavbar but they still overwrite it. what is the correct way to create different sections?

[image]

> i added a red background for the home section so its easier to see what its doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to do something like this for your sidebar to fix it on the side and have it take up the full screen.

This will fix the sidebar in a position on the screen (0px away from the top and 0px away from the bottom).

You then define the width and you have a fixed sidebar!

Hope that helps!

```css
.sidebar {
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='sidebar'></div>
```

Comment: I tried applying those styles but the problem still remains, the sidebar gets overwrited by different components

Comment: Hey @thugcat85, are you able to recreate it in a JS Fiddle because it's hard to see what you're working with since this code I posted works? You can also try using `!important` after each property that is being overwritten.

Comment: Hello , i got it fixed now by applying your css style to the sidebar and setting backgroud : none  for the sections

Comment: Glad to hear it @thugcat85!